# JSON.stringify not working and inserting in database while sending array in post

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I'm trying to send an array in post using ajax to my file "addServicesRequest.php", which will then insert one by one the data into the database.

I've done multiple test and it seems that the ajax isn't sending because the alert sucess "Ok" isn't showing.

Does somebody knows why it isn't working please ?

```
function totalBeforeSubmit(){

var totalService = $('#totalPriceService').val();

var globalTotal = 0;

var getI = [];

for(var i = 0; i <= totalService; i++){

    if($('#'+i).is(":checked")){

        var total = $('#'+i).val();

        globalTotal = parseInt(globalTotal )+ parseInt(total); 

        getI[i] = $('#'+i).closest('.form-control').find('.iHidden').html(); 

    }
}

//PROBLEM HERE:

$('.calculatePrice').click(function(){

    var jsonString = JSON.stringify(getI); 
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "addServicesRequest.php",
        data: {data : getI}, 
        cache: false,

        success: function(){
            alert("OK");
        }
    });

});



alert(globalTotal);

if(globalTotal == 0){
    window.location.replace('addServices.php');
    alert('Veuillez selectionner un ou des services avant de valider');

    return false;

} else {

    return true;
}
}
```

in addServicesRequest.php :

```
<?php

 require_once('connectDatabase.php');

 $data = json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['data']));


 foreach($data as $d){

$insert = $bdd->prepare('INSERT INTO chosen_services (id_service) VALUES (:id_service)');

$insert->execute(array(
        "id_service" => $d
));

}

header('Location: addServices.php');


?>
```

Thanks a lot in advance ! I'm really struggling with this

Comment: Have you checked the browser console for errors?

Comment: what's the value you are getting for `getI` after loop?

Comment: if I checked the 2 checkboxes it will be [20,19], and if I check only the second : [null,19]  (image : https://i.ibb.co/4pgRxL1/image.png )

Comment: You don't seem to be using jsonString

Comment: @NewToJS yes I did

Answer (score 1):

Use serialized json

```
var jsonString = JSON.stringify(getI); 
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "addServicesRequest.php",
        data: {data : jsonString}, 
        cache: false,

        success: function(){
            alert("OK");
        }
    });
```

Set true as second param to get an array instead of stdClass

```
$data = json_decode($_POST['data'], true);
```

$data can be false or array, validate it

Answer (score 0):

Use **join** function instead of JSON.strigify.

`getI.join(',')`

It will make all array value in comma separated string.
then pass it in ajax request

and in php use **"explode"** to convert in again array

`explode(',', $_POST['data'])`

I hope it will work.. !!

Comment: still dosen't work :( the ajax doen't send the data

Comment: Try JSON.stringify(getI.join(','));

Comment: data is passing or not ?

Comment: is data passing in below code ?
var jsonString = JSON.stringify(getI);

Comment: can you share me your requested data screen ?